# I want to create a player that moves back and forth along an arc for the game I am creating in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I want the player to move along an arc going back and forth and if the spacebar is pressed then the player switches directions, essentially turning around. I've gone through a lot of iterations of this function but the code provided has the best looking arc, I just can't get it to switch directions properly.

vvv This is what I am currently using that has a nice looking arc vvv

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f; // speed of player movement
    public float arcHeight = 1f; // height of the arc that the player moves along
    public float arcRadius = 8f; // length of the arc that the player moves along

    private float direction = 1f; // direction of player movement

    private Vector3 startPosition; // starting position of the player

    private bool movingRight = true;

    void Start()
    {
        // startPosition = transform.position; // save starting position
    }

    void Update()
    {

        // move player along an arc
        float x = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, arcRadius) - arcRadius / 2f;
        float y = startPosition.y + Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Max(0f, arcRadius * arcRadius - x * x)) + arcHeight;

        // update player position
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y - 12, 0f);

        // reverse direction when spacebar is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // direction *= -1f;


            //I don't think I need the following code It seems to work fine without it
            // check if the player has gone beyond the end of the arc and needs to reverse direction
            if (transform.position.x < -arcRadius / 2f && movingRight)
            {
                movingRight = false;
            }
            else if (transform.position.x > arcRadius / 2f && !movingRight)
            {
                movingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few other things I tried (Update Functions only):

```
    void Update()
    {
        // calculate the current position of the player along the arc
        float progress = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, arcLength);
        float x = Mathf.Lerp(startPosition.x - arcLength / 2f, startPosition.x + arcLength / 2f, progress / arcLength);
        float y = startPosition.y + direction * Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Max(arcHeight * arcHeight - Mathf.Pow(x - startPosition.x, 2), 0f));

        // update the position of the player
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0f);

        // check if the spacebar is pressed to switch the direction of movement along the arc
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            direction *= -1f;
        }
    }
```

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            movingRight = !movingRight;
        }

        float direction = movingRight ? 1f : -1f;
        float horizontalMovement = direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float arcAngle = horizontalMovement / arcRadius;

        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
        newPosition.x += horizontalMovement;
        newPosition.y = Mathf.Sin(arcAngle) * arcHeight;
        transform.position = newPosition;
    }
```